# Clean Analytics in Sitecore 8

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, reporting

I need to do a clean test in Sitecore Analytics. I have cleaned all Analytics but if I remount the path Analyser all results are brought back. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First Method (recommended):**

Install the [Analytics Database Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Analytics_Database_Manager.aspx) version 3.0

- When Analytics Database Manager is installed, access the application from the Sitecore
  launchpad.
- Go on the "REMOVE OLD DATA" tab, select the desired options and click start.

**Second Method:**

- Delete your MongoDB Databases related to the Sitecore instance.
- Replace the Reporting Database with a clean copy of the corresponding Sitecore version or use the **__DeleteAllReportingData**  stored procedure in /Programmability/Stored Procedures .

[image]

- Restart your Sitecore Instance.

Comment: I am not sure if ADM is compatible with Sitecore 8 onwards

Comment: I am currently using the version 3.0 without issues on  8.2 rev. 161221

Answer (score 3):

The quick and dirty way that I do it in dev on a regular basis is to:

1. Replace your reporting database with a new DB from the sitecore zip file /databases.
2. Using robomongo, log into Mongo and delete your xDB databases. ([yoursite]_analytics, [yoursite]_tracking_contact, [yoursite]_tracking_live, [yoursite]_tracking_live).

When you visit the site for the first time, Sitecore will make new xDB databases in Mongo.