# Clean Analytics in Sitecore 9

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, xconnect

Is there a way to remove Analytics data in Sitecore 9? Similar question for [Sitecore 8](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/clean-analytics-in-sitecore-8) which talked about the use of __DeleteAllReportingData and deletion of Mongodbs or the use of [Analytics_Database_Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Analytics_Database_Manager.aspx)

I've searched, but didnt find anything about Sitecore 9 Analytics Data.

If any knows, please let us know. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To clean the sql xdb database in Sitecore 9 you need to run bellow script in SQL on every shard that you have .

```
USE [yourdatabaseprefix.Collection.ShardX]

GO

DELETE FROM [xdb_collection].ContactIdentifiers

Delete from [xdb_collection].ContactFacets

Delete from [xdb_collection].InteractionFacets

Delete from [xdb_collection].Interactions

Delete from [xdb_collection].Contacts
```

### Updated for 9.1

Add these also for 9.1

```
Delete from [xdb_collection].ContactIdentifiersIndex
Delete from [xdb_collection].DeviceProfileFacets
Delete from [xdb_collection].DeviceProfiles
Delete from [xdb_collection].DeviceProfileFacets
Delete from [xdb_collection].DeviceProfileFacets
```

You also need to clean the interactions out of the processing pool

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [xdb_processing_pools].[InteractionLiveProcessingPool]
```

If you use SOLR you need to update xdb solr index:

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/rebuild-index/rebuild-solr-index.html

For Azure Search you need to use:

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/rebuild-index/rebuild-azure-index.html

You should also to rebuild reporting database:

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/reporting/rebuild-reporting.html

Comment: It's not just about the DB's, it's also the xDB index that xConnect uses. It's the Reporting database that Sitecore uses.

Comment: I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks @VladIobagiu. really appreciate your comprehensive answer. I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: We did this for a 9.0.1 instance that the processing server quit aggregating data. There were no errors in the logs, but a lot of warnings about not being able to find a contact in xconnect. Sitecore support advised us to clear the data in the InteractionLiveProcessingPool table in the Processing.Pools database and rebuild the reporting database which fixed our issue. Hopefully this will help anyone else who may have the same issue.

Comment: Why are the deletes not a "truncate" on the collections in the same way as the "processing pool" had truncates?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Vlad on deleting the xdb shared data. But I would also restore a clean/fresh reporting database. Otherwise you have to rebuild the reporting DB to clean up the analytics reporting.

Comment: In my case, i was still able to see older data even after rebuilding the reporting DB. Later I had to restart the IIS to get cleaned up Analytics reporting.